# I want to deactivate each button by parameter in rails attendance application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is an application that records the time when entering a break, ending a break, and going to work, but I am wondering how to express the following requirements by programming.

Requirement 1 If you are at work, deactivate the work button

Requirement 2 If the break has started, deactivate the break start button and activate the break end button.

Requirement 3 If the break has started and the break end button has not been pressed, deactivate the leave button.

Requirement 4 If the break start and break end have been performed once and the break start has been pressed again, the break end button is activated and the break start button is deactivated.

To achieve this functionality, we have defined a decorator for Attendance (a database model that records attendance and break) as shown below.

```rb
module AttendanceDecorator
  def work_in_button
    button_to "work_in", attendances_work_in_path , {:disabled=> work_in != nil}
  end

  def break_in_button
    if work_in == nil
      button_to "break_in", attendances_break_in_path, {:disabled=> true }
    elsif break_in != nil && break_out != nil && break_out < break_in
      button_to "break_in", attendances_break_in_path, {:disabled=> true }
    elsif break_in == nilい
      button_to "break_in", attendances_break_in_path, {:disabled=> false }
    elsif break_out == nil
      button_to "break_in", attendances_break_in_path, {:disabled=> true }
    else
      button_to "break_in", attendances_break_in_path, {:disabled=> false }
    end
  end

  def break_out_button
    if work_in == nil
      button_to "break_out", attendances_break_out_path, {:disabled=> true }
    elsif break_in != nil && break_out != nil && break_out < break_in
      button_to "break_out", attendances_break_out_path, {:disabled=> false}
    elsif break_in == nil 
      button_to "break_out", attendances_break_out_path, {:disabled=> true}
    elsif break_out != nil 
      button_to "break_out", attendances_break_out_path, {:disabled=> true}
    else 
      button_to "break_out", attendances_break_out_path, {:disabled=> false}
    end
  end

  def work_out_button
    if work_in == nil
      button_to "work_out", attendances_work_out_path, {:disabled=> true }
    elsif !break_in && break_out
      button_to "work_out", attendances_work_out_path, {:disabled=> true }
    else
      button_to "work_out", attendances_work_out_path, {:disabled=> false }
    end
  end
end
```

This is the attendance table scheme

```
  create_table "attendances", charset: "utf8mb3", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "work_in"
    t.datetime "break_in"
    t.datetime "break_out"
    t.datetime "work_out"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_attendances_on_user_id"
  end
```

I'm wondering if the above code has a slightly complicated conditional branch and can be expressed more simply. Is there any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

The classic "status" problem.

An object can be in only one of the states:

```rb
require 'awesome_print'

$last_action = {
  work_in: 2,
  break_in: 1,
  break_out: 1,
  work_out: 1
}.max_by{|k,v| v}[0]

print '$last_action: '.red; puts $last_action

def work?
  $last_action == :work_in || $last_action == :break_out
end
def break?
  $last_action == :break_in
end
def rest?
  $last_action == :work_out
end

puts work?
puts break?
puts rest?

def work_in_button
  return :disabled if work? || break?
  :anabled
end

def break_in_button
  return :disabled if rest? || break?
  :anabled
end

def break_out_button
  return :disabled if rest? || work?
  :anabled
end

def work_out_button
  return :disabled if rest? || break?
  :anabled
end

print 'work_in_button: '; puts work_in_button
print 'break_in_button: '; puts break_in_button
print 'break_out_button: '; puts break_out_button
print 'work_out_button: '; puts work_out_button
```

=>>>

```
$last_action: work_in
true
false
false
work_in_button: disabled
break_in_button: anabled
break_out_button: disabled
work_out_button: anabled
```

Comment: How should I update last_action?

Comment: Also, how should the initial value of lastaction be defined?

Comment: You carry out calculations in the decorator based on four parameters at once (work_in, break_in, break_out, work_out), but the object (user) has only three states. last_action is just the last action of the user (determined by the maximum time of four fields).
     t.datetime "work_in"
     t.datetime "break_in"
     t.datetime "break_out"
     t.datetime "work_out"
So I don't understand the question "How should I update last_action?"

Comment: If all four times are null, then most likely the user has not started work? This is just another check at the beginning of the calculation, I really missed it.